# Matplotlib window appears at the back?

Tags: python, macos, plot, matplotlib

Whenever I call `show()` in matplotlib the plot window appears behind all other windows and I have to minimize everything to see it. Is there any way I can prevent this or programmatically bring it to the front. On OSX Lion. Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. This answer is presented in the comments to the accepted answer but I think it deserves to have a place as a separate one as it solves the issue nicely. Besides the author's problem I additionally had the problem that matplotlib window wasn't in the tray of active windows so I couldn't switch to it by `<Alt>+<Tab>`.

Changing of the matplotlib's default backend `macosx` solved everything. You can try immediately in your code like this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt5agg")
```

`Qt5agg` might not be presented in your system then please pick the one that is. You can find them:

```
import matplotlib.rcsetup as rcsetup
print(rcsetup.all_backends)
```

If it helped then you might want to change your backend in the configuration. For that locate it first:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
```

Then change `backend:` value:

```
backend      : macosx
```

to your backend. I used in the end:

```
backend      : TkAgg
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but I'm using [ipython](http://ipython.org/) instead of the default python console. When launched it with `ipython --pylab` I can plot e.g. by typing

```
>> plot([1,3,2])
```

and have the plot pop up in front. It also has some other very nice features ;)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behavior with both python and ipython on my 10.9.1 system so it's not necessarily a solution in every case.

Comment: Same here. I believe anddam is experiencing the same issue I am, which is that the matplotlib window is _permanently_ behind all other windows. I cannot bring it into focus, even when clicking on it in mission control. The only workaround I've so far figured out is to use mission control to temporarily drop the window _into an empty space_, then switch to that space, put the window in focus, and then drag the window _back to my original space_, where the z-order will finally be correct (unless I click on any other windows, which causes it to immediately return to the back again).

Comment: **Update:** The TkAgg backend does not have the same problem; it is given a top-level window (i.e. you can switch to it using Cmd-Tab). It still starts at the bottom of the z-order, but it behaves normally now. I think there must be a bug in the MacOSX backend in Mavericks.

Comment: @NeilTraft's solution works for me. To make TkAgg default backend, find your [matplotlibrc file](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/customizing.html) and change the line `backend: macosx` to `backend: TkAgg`

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib developer's seem to be aware of this issue. But looking into https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/596 it looks like it's going to be a while until getting a solution, apparently because some people find it annoying that figure.show() "steals" screen space.

Answer (score 0):

It may be OS-specific, but using interactive plotting (which plots as soon as you instruct) causes figures to come up in the foreground as soon *as they're made* on Ubuntu:

```
import pylab as P
P.ion()
P.figure(1)
P.plot([1,2,3],[1,4,9])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same set-up as nickponline. What works for me is:

```
from pylab import get_current_fig_manager()
get_current_fig_manager().window.raise_()
```

If you have multiple figures, this only raises the currently active one. For that case, I found that the following works:

```
fig1=figure(1)
cfm1=get_current_fig_manager().window

fig2=figure(2)
cfm2=get_current_fig_manager().window
...
cfm1.activateWindow()
cfm1._raise()
pause(.1)  # or something else that uses up some time
cfm2.activateWindow()
cfm2.raise_()
```

Comment: the import line has a trailing '()', also there seems to be no more window property in FigureManager