# How do I keep the focus on the command prompt when calling pylab.show?

Tags: python, matplotlib, focus

I am calling a python script from the comandline (bash under Ubuntu):

```
> python myScript.py
```

within this script, I create a figure, show it (nonblocking) with PyLab and wait for a user entry:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('TkAgg')
import pylab as pl

fig = pylab.figure()
# Figure gets some content here
pl.show(block=False)
inp = raw_input('Please enter your choice: ') # Prompt window has no focus
```

Now my problem is, that the figure window, that is poping up, has the focus. But I want the focus to stay at or return to the command line window for interaction with the raw_input...

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matplotlib window appears at the back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391391/matplotlib-window-appears-at-the-back)

Comment: nope - I actually want to have the Matplotlib window in the back of the command promt (the opposite of what is described in that discussion) - but no information there how to force this (there wrong) behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Some other lower level backends tend not to do it, try:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
```

Comment: I've tried some other backends to no success (incl. 'Agg')